# Asking for user input raises an IO TypeError in Python

Tags: python, io, pickle

I'm writing a simple task logger that uses the `pickle` module to store class objects persistently. It seems to work fine, but for some reason I am getting the error

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
'_io.BufferedReader' object is not callable
  File "/path/to/directory/main.py", line 43, in ask
    arg = input("")
  File "/path/to/directory/main.py", line 49, in <module>
    ask()
```

when calling the function `ask()` which is as follows:

```
def ask():
    while True:
        arg = input("")
        if arg == "add":
            addTask(input("What is the task? "),input("When's it due? "),input("What's the category? "))
        else:
            print("Command not recognized")
```

The function creates an object of the class `task` which is what is pickled. The class is defined as follows:

```
class task:
    def __init__(self, name, date, category):
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
        self.category = category
    def expand(self): # returns the contents of the task
        print(self.name + " is due " + self.date)
```

I want to say that it's an issue with Pickle as that has caused me the most headaches so far, and the error appears to be I/O based...

I ran the VSCode debugger on it to no help.

Comment: You probably have overwritten `input` somewhere: you likely defined a variable named `input` outside the function?

Comment: I don't see pickle being referenced anywhere in your code. I'd suspect @ Willem Van Onsem is correct here, but you should include enough code to reproduce the error if that doesn't fix it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Fixed, thanks. I'll flag an answer if you put one out.